# Run Selenium IDE Test Cases from CMD

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

I am preparing to run Selenium IDE test cases from command line and redirect results to log file using the below command:

```
java -jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -multiwindow  -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://newtours.demoaut.com" "C:\Selenium\Invalid_Login.html" "C:\selenium\logs\hi.html"
```

I am running the above using *.bat file but it's not working for me as it's just open firefox showing me IDE pannels and code without running it.

Can you Please help ?

Thank you !

Comment: does that command work when you run it on the command line, not in the batch file?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have in your `C:\Selenium\` folder all the following:

- selenium server standalone `.jar` file
- YourTestSuite.html
- YourTestCase.html
- `.bat` file created with your (more or less) mentioned command

`java -jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://newtours.demoaut.com" "C:\Selenium\YourTestSuite.html" "C:\Selenium\logs\hi.html"`

Steps to troubleshoot your setup:

1. Since I can't tell what it is, make sure that `Invalid_Login.html` is your actually test suite and NOT your test case.
2. Use selenium server standalone jar file version according to your browser version. For latest version of browser, you need to use latest selenium server standalone jar file in your test

Comment: yes, it must be a suite file, not a test file. Double check that.